# Relative distance of a value along the plane

Tags: analysis

[I have to calculate M value which is mentioned in the image. I know the (X0,Y0) , (X1,Y1) , (X2,Y2) and so on. I don't know how to calculate the value of M in  (X1,Y1) and (X2,Y2) and so on. This is required to compute M values along the plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8TTn.png)

X0 = 10712690.9156759, Y0=1678768.49130763 , M0=0

X1 = 10722964.4080267, Y1=1679010.25979067, ?

Xn = 10805259.26, Yn= 1678675.774 , Mn=3560

and distance between X0 and X1  is 10276.33675 and this is point how to calculate the M value?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I have got distance between (X0,Y0) and (X1,Y1) which is (X1-X0)*2+(Y1-Y0)*2 and then take SQRT of it. But at that point how to identify M value? any Formula will help?